# How does energy distribute through a lattice?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

The text that I am reading (*Concepts in Thermal Physics* by Blundell) gives an example of a simulation in which energy distributes throughout a lattice. The lattice contains 400 atoms and the initial configuration assigns 1 quantum of energy to each atom. Then it chooses one atom at random, removes a quantum of energy from that atom and place it on a second, randomly chosen atom. Here is a diagram from the text:

[image]

As this process repeats for many iterations, we obtain the Boltzmann distribution. The problem I have with this is that energy can move from one atom to a distant atom without going through all of the atoms in between. Why is this allowed?

Comment: Please explain how you concluded that "that energy can move from one atom to a distant atom without going through all of the atoms in between" to start with.

Comment: For example, if you look at how the system went from (a) to (b) in the diagram, it seems as if energy went from one atom to a distant atom after just one iteration.

Comment: Moving from a) to b) is not iteration, rather is the initial condition, that is, you are forcing the algorithm to start iteration, taking b) as the initial values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a conceptual model, don't read too much physics into it. If you like, you can think that between one step and the next the quantum of energy travels along the board and finally settles in another position.

I want also to point out that the effect shown can also be obtained by allowing the quanta to move only to adjacent squares.

The following is the result of a quick simulation I ran, allowing the quanta to move only to adjacent squares.

[image: gif evolution of the sistem]

An the final distribution is

[image: histogram of final distribution]

Comment: Thank you. The visuals are very helpful. I saw that you also answered my question on what it means for all microstates for a given macrostate to be equally likely. Based on this model you've posted, is it correct to say that while not all microstates are equally probable as you go from one step to the next (since energy is only allowed to move to adjacent cells), the system will explore all energy configuration an equal number of times in the long run?

Comment: @roflmfao yes it is correct. This property is called _ergodicity_, and it is extremely important in statistical mechanics. When it doesn't hold, you get lots of interesting consequences, like symmetry breaking and phase transitions. Look up the _2D Ising model_: a simple system where, depending on temperature, ergodicity may or may not be broken.

Comment: @roflmfao reading your comment again, I realized I have misunderstood you. Ergodicity is not the property that each microstate is visited the same number of times. Instead it means that in the long run each microstate is visited a number of times proportional to the ensemble probability of that state. In your case, every microstate has the same probability, therefore these two statements are equivalent, in this case